# How do I perform frequently file reading/writing operations(multi-thread) in python?

Tags: python, file-io

Here's my problem: I need to perform frequently reading/writing operations to one file via different threads, and I tend to use threading.RLock().acquire() and threading.RLock().release() to lock the resource(e.g., one txt file). The thing is, you can easily do file writing operations in a certain thread, how do you get the return value in the thread? Here's my sample code:

```
FileLock = threading.RLock()

def FileReadingWriting(self, Input, Mode)

    #### Input: things to write
    #### Mode:    1    -    write to the file
    ####          2    -    read from the file

    FileLock.acquire()

    if Mode == 1:
        TheFile = open("example.txt", "w")
        TheFile.write(Input)
        TheFile.close()
    elif Mode == 2:
        TheFile = open("example.txt", "r")
        Content = TheFile.read()
        TheFile.close()

        return Content #### Obviously this won't work, but if I want to get the content in a thread, how should I code?

    FileLock.release()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some variable accessible both to the worker thread and to the main thread.

For example, worker thread can get as an input a reference to some object and fill it when done. Main thread will wait workers threads to finish, then will check the objects.